# React Navigation 4 MaterialTopTabNavigator - activeLabelStyle

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am creating a MaterialTopBar with React Navigation v4. I am facing an issue where i am not able to style to active state of the label - or even the tab.

The docs state that you can supply a function which renders a custom label. Here you could supply a custom style based on the `focused` parameter. This is what i am doing, but it seems like it just ignores my custom label function. Below is my code.

```
export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
 {
    Drinks: {
      screen: PickupDrinksScreen,
    },
    Food: {
      screen: PickupFoodScreen,
    },
    Snacks: {
      screen: PickupSnacksScreen,
    }
  },
 {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
        tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => {
          const { routeName } = navigation.state;
          return <Text style={[styles.label, focused && styles.focusedLabel]}>{routeName}</Text>;
        }
      };
    }
 })
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve this inside a BottomTabNavigator but I think that it does not really differ for your needs. Check out my code:

```
  Secure: {
    screen: SecureStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        if (focused) {
          return <Ionicons name="md-unlock" size={24} color="#ccc" />;
        } else {
          return <Ionicons name="md-lock" size={24} color="#ccc" />;
        }
      },
      title: "Secure"
    }
  }
```

try it like I did, I pass the navigationOptions right to the screen instead of passing it to all tabs. ~ Faded